# What is the source of packet size in a GET request?

Tags: http, networking

I am analyzing HTTP network traffic from different websites. I have noticed that GET packet size differs between websites.

I thought that URI length decided the packet size, yet different websites have different values. For example "GET /" has a size of 339 for one website, yet 390 for another.

Also, I noticed that some websites with longer URI text have smaller GET packet sizes, and vice versa.

Who is responsible for the size of GET packet? Is it the browser, client, server or who?

Thanks

Comment: "Who is responsible?" all of the above

Comment: Do you mean the actual GET request, or the response to it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the discrepancy you are observing is probably due either to different host headers or to the passing of cookies between client and server, although referrer could be another source of variation.

A given `GET` packet is of the following format. In the case of the below example, the packet size is 361 bytes.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: google.com\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n
Keep-Alive: 300\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

The first line is determined by the URL; however, all subsequent lines are headers. Headers are passed by the client to communicate details of the expected response and the current request to the server.

Additionally, the response from the server will be a packet. This packet, too, will have headers which are chosen explicitly to communicate certain information to the other party.